# sigClicked not triggered on pyqtgraph PlotCurveItem

Tags: python, pyqtgraph, pyside6

I am using pyqtgraph 0.13.2 with PySide6. The below code, I can't seem to get the `PlotCurveItem` to trigger, and print "working". It also does not work with `PlotDataItem`. I feel like I am doing something very obviously wrong, but can't figure it out...

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PySide6 import QtWidgets
import sys

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):

        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(lay)

        self.graphics_layout_widget = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        lay.addWidget(self.graphics_layout_widget)

        self.plot = self.graphics_layout_widget.addPlot(0, 0)

        data = np.random.randn(1000)
        self.peak_plot = pg.PlotCurveItem(data)
        self.peak_plot.sigClicked.connect(self.test)
        
        self.plot.addItem(self.peak_plot)

    def test(self):
        print("working")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: [`setClickable(True)`](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/graphicsItems/plotcurveitem.html#pyqtgraph.PlotCurveItem.setClickable)